# My raspberry pi routes all traffic to tun0, but I need to add an exception to allow ssh incoming connection from wlan0

Tags: linux, iptables

My Raspberry Pi routes all traffic generated inside the machine to a VPN tunnel in **tun0** interface, all communications are cipher through the VPN.
This is the rule I am using to get this:

```
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
```

But I don't get any response when I try accessing the Raspberry Pi via ssh from the Internet through the IP in the non-secure interface **wlan0**. I think the current iptables rule is blocking the ssh incoming connections.

I would like to allow ssh connections from the internet in a specific origin IP from wlan0, without loosing the functionality that I already have (all outcoming connections originated on the Raspberry through the VPN tunnel **tun0**).

Could you please guys give a hand on this?

Comment: I don't think it's your `MASQUERADE` rule that's causing the problem. According to the documentation on the iptables nat table, "This table is consulted when a packet that creates a new connection  is  encountered.". But your SSH `SYN|ACK`s won't be new connections. I expect you should look at your routing table as the culprit instead. It's probably set to route all of 0/0 and ::/0 except for the address of the VPN endpoint through the VPN.

Comment: I am not an expert in iptables, could you please tell me the command I should use?

Comment: Please read my comment. My suspicion is that you do not *have* an iptables problem.